# Clustered column chart for count of dates visualization in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a report with months in X-axis and count of tickets created/closed on Y-axis from the data shown below. Based on what field I use in X-axis, I am getting different results. My expected result would have created=1/closed=3 in the month of December. Please help me understand what I am missing and how to achieve it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Data for replication:

CreatedDate ClosedDate  Name
1/9/2019 6:20:08 PM null    CR00010001
4/2/2019 5:42:49 PM null    CR00010002
5/8/2019 4:23:33 PM null    CR00010003
8/2/2019 6:15:33 PM null    CR00010004
10/8/2019 4:02:56 PM    null    CR00010005
10/22/2019 3:17:45 PM   null    CR00010006
10/23/2019 5:05:17 PM   null    CR00010007
1/4/2019 10:12:45 PM    1/29/2019 4:57:48 PM    CR00010008
1/16/2019 10:19:30 PM   1/30/2019 6:55:42 PM    CR00010009
1/10/2019 3:09:03 PM    2/6/2019 6:43:23 PM CR00010010
4/10/2019 7:59:29 PM    4/24/2019 1:05:14 PM    CR00010011
3/14/2019 3:02:52 PM    4/29/2019 6:28:20 PM    CR00010012
3/12/2019 8:44:11 PM    4/29/2019 6:29:06 PM    CR00010013
4/29/2019 6:55:07 PM    5/10/2019 2:57:53 PM    CR00010014
5/1/2019 6:39:32 PM 5/29/2019 4:41:11 PM    CR00010015
5/21/2019 9:50:39 PM    7/25/2019 5:42:17 PM    CR00010016
6/4/2019 3:34:34 PM 8/5/2019 8:20:58 PM CR00010017
1/2/2019 1:55:28 PM 9/19/2019 2:46:50 PM    CR00010018
8/27/2019 6:54:56 PM    10/15/2019 5:19:01 PM   CR00010019
10/15/2019 5:27:23 PM   10/24/2019 4:00:09 PM   CR00010020
10/25/2019 11:30:21 PM  10/30/2019 1:42:59 PM   CR00010021
11/1/2019 6:18:11 PM    11/12/2019 7:41:13 PM   CR00010022
11/20/2019 3:18:07 PM   12/6/2019 2:41:22 PM    CR00010023
10/21/2019 3:45:28 PM   12/6/2019 4:20:14 PM    CR00010024
12/10/2019 11:43:09 PM  12/13/2019 4:42:22 PM   CR00010025

Comment: Well in your first picture you use the table `Date`. Does this table have a relationship with your other table `PG1_Query_CR`? The second and the theird picture are the same. But note if you use just `Month` as axis all months are displayed independet from the year.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, should there be one? Updated the pictures and data as I previously included 2018 as well. Just need it for 2019 data.

Comment: Yes there should be a relationship between your `Date` table and your table were you get the values from, otherwise the visual wont work. Just stick with the second picture, this are the right values.

Comment: Extracted Name of the month from CreatedDate & ClosedDate as new columns and added a relationship with Date-Months. But depending on which relationship is active between Created month/Closed month, another column in the report is incorrect as from the pictures 3 and 4. FYI, I added the relationship picture.

Comment: would USEREALTIONSHIP be of help in this situation, if you have active and inactive realtionships

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where I would add it and how?  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in Power BI community forum, fyi:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Clustered-column-chart-for-count-of-dates-visualization-in/m-p/880962#M422240